# Unable to retrieve Codeigniter Session

Tags: codeigniter, session

Am using ajax for login auth.
Setting session in controller and returning a value. If value is '1'; am redirecting him to profile using ajax.
Am unable to retrieve session data in profile function.
But able to print session data in same function where session has been set.

here is code.
**Comtroller:

```
if($row['is_verified'] == '1')
{
$info['details'] = 'user_id,role_id';
$info['type'] = 'email_id';
$info['data'] = $this->input->post('email');
$userdata = $this->tseng_model->get_userdata($info);
$data = array(
'UserID' => $row['user_id'],
'RoleID' => $row['role_id']
);
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
echo "1";}
public function profile()
{
  print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
}
```

my ajax code which is successfully redirecting to page

```
if(data==1)
{
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href='<?php echo site_url('tseng/profile') ?>' }, 3000);
}
```

But unable to retrieve data in profile function..

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that in your config.php, that you have the cookie security set properly.

For SSL Connections:

```
$config['cookie_secure']    = true;
```

For Non-SSL Connections:

```
$config['cookie_secure']    = false;
```

Comment: Its already set to false. as am running this with Non-SSL only.

Comment: i would then try setting your userdata to a new cookie before redirecting.  i've done that to make CI's pesky sessions actually work!

Comment: Yeah i vl try to make cookies ! But what;s the problem with the session :?
i would like to know the reason.. !!
Thank you for your help..

Comment: codeigniter destroys your session and recreate it everytime a page is loaded/refreshed.  i have always gotten around it by either checking my cookie settings, or creating a cookie with the data i need

Comment: So you say that now i cant use session !..?